# with sed, how can I replace word within a matching line?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am trying to write a sed expression to detect lines similar to this:

`s0:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 115200 ttyS0 linux`

and replace the `ttys0` with `something_else`

I do not want to detect commented out lines (beginning with `#`)

I can replace the whole line, but how to I just replace the substring, leaving the rest of the line intact ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows:

```
echo 's0:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 115200 ttyS0 linux' | 
    sed -e '/^[^#]/ s/ttyS0/foo/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the part before ttyS0 and those after ttyS0, also check if line doesn't begin with `#`:

`sed 's/^[^#]\(.*\)ttyS0\(.*\)/\1something\2/'`

Result:

```
%> echo "s0:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 115200 ttyS0 linux" | sed 's/^[^#]\(.*\)ttyS0\(.*\)/\1something\2/'
0:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 115200 something linux
```

Comment: You don't need last group and `\2` at all. Also if it is possible it's much better do not use backreference cause usually it eats too many resources.

Answer (score 0):

If it always starts with `s[number]colon` you could do (with GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^s[0-9]+:/s/ttyS0/something_else/' infile
```

Which changes any line that starts with the regex, adapt to suit your needs.